# DispEx Redirecting not working for pdf documents

Tags: pdf, sharepoint

I have some problem with `DispEx` function.
I open `.pdf` document in client app (Adobe Acrobat Reader DC) using `DispEx` function, and after closing client app my page should reload (its works for `.docx` documents), but it does not work. I verify `g_varSkipRefreshOnFocu` var and its value is `0`, as MS recommends.

Example:

```
DispEx(dispCtx, evnt, "True", "False",
            "False", "AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments", "1", actXClass, "", "",
            "", "1", "0", "0", "0x7fffffffffffffff");
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing **evnt** to **event** and **actXClass** to **"AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments"** worked for me (this is a link in a repeater row - so I used single-quotes, but you get the idea - **Eval("Name")** grabs the file name from my query and uses it to create the path to the document within its Document Library):

```
<A onclick="return DispEx(this,event,'TRUE','FALSE','FALSE','AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments','1','AdobeAcrobat.OpenDocuments','','','','1','0','0','0x7fffffffffffffff')" href='<%# string.Format("/DocumentLibrary/{0}",Eval("Name")) %>'>Edit Document</A>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wiil try